# FCM Token on iOS Safari Changing Frequently

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on adding Firebase Cloud Messaging to my web app, and I'm a bit confused about when to get the device token. Right now, I'm getting it every time someone opens a page in my app, but I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Especially on iOS Safari, I'm facing issues. I've noticed that the token changes often, even though information online suggests it shouldn't (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4132). Unfortunately, I can't pinpoint when or why these changes happen. In my view, I find it necessary to check the token every time the app is called to address this challenge. However, I'm still a bit puzzled about the frequent changes and their reasons.

Also, I'm wondering if there's a way to determine whether the token returned by `getToken` is freshly generated or an old one. This information would be valuable in deciding whether I should send it back to my server for storage. Currently, I'm sending it back every time, causing a significant amount of unnecessary overhead. Any insights or suggestions on optimizing this process would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!